# How is UKIP seen in the United States and elsewhere?

Tags: united-kingdom, parties, libertarianism, public-opinion

I wonders whether UKIP is even known outside of Europe.

UKIP is the [United Kingdom Independence Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Independence_Party), which campaign on the right to self determination and libertarianism.

Comment: I live in the US and I personally haven't heard of the UKIP before

Comment: Google search for ""United Kingdom Independence Party"" shows 120,000 results. Not big.

Comment: The only reason I know of ukip is because I read the Economist. That said, I doubt most Americans can tell you the two parties in Cameron's coalition. Beyond "Tory" and "Labor" we are lost. Lib-dems, you say?

Comment: "What's the UKIP?"

Comment: @AffableGeek - Tory? Didn't we kick their behinds couple hundred years ago?

Comment: @DVK Would have done the world a favour if you hadn't stopped at your own borders with the buttkicking!

Comment: I hang in American conservative circles, where UKIP is generally seen favorably. In particular, they tend to align with the Republican Party on key issues, such as welfare, taxes and border security. But we're talking about people who are highly engaged in politics; your average American probably knows squat about that.

Comment: since UKIP made some headlines after their recent victory in UK European election - nothing in US news headlines (or elsewhere). I guess closer to Scottish independence vote UKIP may get more attention.

Comment: @Chaffers in the case you missed my previous question on UKIP: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/ukip-is-it-real-major-third-party-in-uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few Americans know about the UKIP itself, but a lot of right-wingers in the US hail Nigel Farage's speeches in the European Parliament as telling what they perceive to be the truth about the Euro, the European project, and national sovereignty.  Glenn Beck is a good example.  Look at [this clip](http://www.glennbeck.com/2012/06/15/hear-the-best-eu-speech-ever-politician-rips-%E2%80%98the-euro-titanic%E2%80%99-that-has-%E2%80%98already-hit-the-iceberg%E2%80%99/), for instance.

Comment: Glenn Beck is one person. Famous and influential one, but ONE. Where'd "a lot of right-wingers" come from?

Comment: @DVK It's just an example.  I could try to find more examples.  I've seen a lot of people talk about Nigel Farage's speeches

Comment: Is the path the EU and the Euro is taking a cause for concern in America? The impression we get over the pond is that Obama withes the US of A could join!

Comment: @Chaffers Part of the reason right-wingers in the US like Nigel Farage is that they have similar fears about the United Nations that Farage has about the European Union, so they view what's happening in Europe as the shape of things to come.  The American left, on the other hand, tends to take a more cosmopolitan view.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some articles in the Swedish press they are often described as a xenophobic (sometimes racist) and far right party.([SvD](http://www.svd.se/nyheter/valet2014/temperaturen-hojs-infor-eu-valet_3563878.svd?sidan=10), [SVT](http://www.svt.se/nyheter/extremhogern-pressar-europa))

Comment: I'm deeply shocked and surprised that left wing journalists (oxymoron, i know) would objectively describe anyone whose politics they disagree with as xenophobic, racist and far right.

Comment: @DVK Actually SvD is right-wing (liberal/conservative) while SVT is considered to be objective.

Comment: And Swedish opinion correlates with US opinion how?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine: The question included "or elsewhere".